# How can I redirect stderr from dialog using newlines as the output record separator?

Tags: bash, dialog, stdout, separator

Every time I run the command I want stderr redirected to */tmp/test*. The test file should have records separated by newlines instead of going to the same line.

If my input for option domain-name-servers is 192.168.0.1 and option routers 192.168.0.2, those two will come out on the same line. They should come out on separate lines.

I am using these IP addresses:

1. 192.168.0.1
2. 192.168.0.2

with this command line:

```
$ dialog --title "Inputbox - Example" \
--inputbox "option domain-name-servers" 8 50 "option domain-name-servers " \
--inputbox "option routers" 8 50 "option routers " \
2> /tmp/test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final code. The *dhcpd.conf* will now have the correct output with newlines for every input from the inputboxes.

```
#!/bin/bash

dialog --title "DHCP-CONFIGURATION" \
dialog --separate-widget $'\n' \
--inputbox "option domain-name-servers" 8 50 "option domain-name-servers "
--inputbox "option routers" 8 50 \ "option routers " 
--inputbox "ddns-update-style" 8 50 \ "ddns-update-style"
--inputbox "subnet and netmask" 8 50 \ "subnet and netmask "
--inputbox "range" 8 50 \ "range "
--inputbox "default-lease-time" 8 50 \ "default-lease-time "
--inputbox "max-lease-time" 8 50 \ "max-lease-time "
--inputbox "}" 8 50 \ "} "
2> /tmp/dhcpd.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use `--separate-widget` Flag

You can use the *--separate-widget* flag to force widgets to be separated by newlines instead of the default tab character. For example:

```
dialog --separate-widget $'\n' \
       --title "Inputbox - Example" \
       --inputbox "option domain-name-servers" 8 50 "option domain-name-servers " \
       --inputbox "option routers" 8 50 "option routers " \
       2> /tmp/test
```